# Typescript, parameter's type is circumvented

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I just stumbled upon the following

```
const myObject = new Object();
myObject['test'] = 'hello';

calc(myObject['test']);

function calc(x: number) {
  console.log(x * 10);
}
```

This is a very simple case.

My expectation was that TypeScript will at least complain at compile time that it can't find the concrete type but `calc` expects a number.

Instead TypeScript won't complain at all and in the console there will be `NaN`.

I first noticed this behavior when using angular 4 and routing data.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '**',
        data: [{error: new ApplicationError('http-status-404', '', HttpErrorStatus.NotFound)}],
        component: ApplicationErrorComponent,
        resolve: {
            error: ApplicationErrorResolve
        }
    }
];

@Injectable()
export class ApplicationErrorResolve implements Resolve<ApplicationError> {

   constructor(private applicationErrorHandler: ApplicationErrorHandler) { }

   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): ApplicationError {

        if (route.data != null && route.data[0]['error'] instanceof ApplicationError) {
            this.applicationErrorHandler.addError(route.data[0]);

            return route.data[0];
        }

        return null;
    }
}

// signature of applicationErrorHandler.addError
addError(error: ApplicationError, navigateToErrorPage: boolean = true) {

}
```

As seen in the code, my object `ApplicationError` would reside in `route.data[0].error` and not `route.data[0]`.
But again TypeScript doesn't complain and during runtime I will just have completly wrong object(type)

Is there something I can do about it (other than manually check with instanceof or similar)?
Like some kind of guard or a switch for typescript (like --strictNullCheck)?

coming from a c# background this left me really surprised (and kinda worried)

**EDIT**

Thanks to Saravana the first part (simple example) works.
But as soon as I use arrays it fails again. even with `noImplictAny = true`

```
 const myArray = new Array<any>();
 myArray[0] = { name: 'test'};
 myArray[1] = { name: 1} ;

 // TypeScript doesn't complain 
 this.calc(myArray[0]);

 // TypeScript doesn't complain
 this.calc(myArray[0].ImActuallyNotPresent);

 function calc(x: number) {
     console.log(x * 10);
 }
```

I don't get it. Why does this work?
I know it has to do with `any` but why would the definition of `myArray` supersede my methods signature?
This makes very little sense to me und gives a false sense of security.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: I think that's because you are using the bracket notation. Try `myObject.test = 'hello';  calc(myObject.test);` and see what happens.

Comment: it does work when using `test` as property. But I think my typed methods should not have to rely on how I provide the parameter.

Comment: brackt notation is kinda reflection technique in javascript determined t runtime. Better to declare an interface and typecast it to it.

Comment: But I don't understand why TypeScript doesn't complain at compile time?
My method has a typed parameter and I provide just "something".
Why does this even work?
Am I missing something in TypeScript?

Comment: @Arikael If you want type checking stop using `any`. Always define types when you need type checking.

Comment: Maybe I completly missunderstand `any`.
But I was under the impression that when my parameter states that it has be `number` and I provide a value of `any` it will fail because `any` is not assignable to `number` (only the other way around).

Why would a value of `any` just overrule any type constraints I defined on my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `"noImplicitAny": true` in your `tsconfig.json` or pass the `--noImplicitAny` flag to the compiler to catch these issues.

If you had turned on `noImplicitAny`, the compiler will check the type of `myObject['test']` against `calc`. Since it is off the type of `myObject['test']` is taken as `any` which disables all type checking allowing it to be passed to `calc`.

With `"noImplicitAny": true`, your example throws the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Object' has no
>   index signature.

TypeScript compiler options: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

---

When you did `const myArray = new Array<any>();` in your example, you are telling the compiler that `myArray` can hold an array of anything. The only thing that the compiler will verify is that `myArray` is an array. The contents of the array can be anything. That is why `myArray[0].ImActuallyNotPresent` does not throw any errors. Because you told the compiler nothing about the contents of the array.

To ensure type checking on the content of the array, provide type information for the array:

```
interface MyArrayContent {
  someString: string;
  someNumber: number
}

const myArray = new Array<MyArrayContent>();
myArray[0] = { someString: 'test', someNumber: 1 };
myArray[1] = { someString: "test2", someNumber: 2};

calc(myArray[0]); // Error
calc(myArray[0].ImActuallyNotPresent); // Error
calc(myArray[0].someString); // Error
calc(myArray[0].someNumber); // No error

function calc(x: number) {
  console.log(x * 10);
}
```

`any` is TypeScript's way to bypass all type-checking and go into full JS-mode and ignore all compile time checks -- which includes verifying that `calc` has a `number` parameter. I understand the confusion. In a language like C# you cannot pass variable of type `object` when a method expects `string` without a cast even when all `string`s are `object`s. But if you think of `any` as synonymous to "disable all type checks wherever this variable is used" it would make much more sense.

`any` documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any

Comment: thanks, this answers the first part (the simple example).
But the second (actual problem with angular) i still unsolved.
I added another example in the question (below EDIT) which shows a problem with arrays.

Comment: thanks again, the problem I had was not that I could use `ImActuallyNotPresent`. That was what I expected because of `any`
But I did not expect that `calc` would accept either `myArray[0]` or `myArray[0].ImActuallyNotPresent` because like you said it could be anything not just a number. But I explicitly told `calc`s parameter `x` to only accept `number`.
That's what I don't get. Why can I provide `any` as argument when I defined that the parameter has to `number`?

Comment: @Arikael `any` is TypeScript's way to bypass all type-checking and go into full JS-mode and ignore all compile time checks -- which includes verifying that `calc` has a `number` parameter. I understand the confusion. In a language like C# you cannot pass variable of type `object`  when a method expects `string` without a cast. But if you think of `any` as synonymous to `disable all type checks` it would make much more sense.

Comment: now I get it, maybe you could add your last comment to your answer because the `disable all type checks` was exactly what I was missunderstanding/missing. Makes me wonder why the angular team decided to use `any` for their routing data instead of `object`